# Can open Word in SharePoint on one computer but not on another, why?

Tags: 2007, document, check-out

Have external users who are able to open and edit Word documents in SharePoint at a university but cannot do so on personal computer at home. What are some of the reasons for this difference?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the user has an up to date (patched) version of Office
   2007 installed.
2. Make sure they are running IE8 or higher
3. Make sure they have added the site to the 'Local Intranet' zone in IE Security Settings.